# show state of a button in jquery when mouse hovers on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I am working on an application using html and jquery. It has 4 buttons that are used to perform various tasks when i click them. what i want now is to show user the state of the button when mouse hover over it. For example for an ON/OFF button if mouse hover over the button it shows user that button is currently OFF or ON.

one way to do this is to use an alert() but with that each time i go to button it will show an alert which i dont want i just want a simple text etc to be displayed on top of the button when mouse hover over it.

anyone can help me how can i do it ?

Comment: What code do you have so far?  Most straightforward route would be to simply change the button's text to reflect the appropriate state.

Comment: @user3298740 If possible, post `html`, `css`, `js` ?

Comment: How do your determine the ON or OFF state of your button?

Answer (score 1):

Change the text of the button on button hover by using **jQuery `.hover()`**:

```
$('button').hover(function(){
    $(this).text('ON');
},function(){
    $(this).text('OFF');
});
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gBsYx/)

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you already know how to get the state of the button, let's assume you assign that state to a variable named... well, `state`. :)

Then it's pretty straightforward from there:

```
$("button").hover(function() { // You may choose a different selector for your buttons
    var curButton = this,
        $curButton = $(this);

    curButton.oldHTML = $curButton.html(); // Cache old button label
    $curButton.html(state); // Change button label to reflect state

}, function() {
    var curButton = this,
        $curButton = $(this);

    $curButton.html(curButton.oldHTML); // Restore old HTML
});
```